# Creating a Scientific Calculator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a scientific calculator and I have a Calculator. My question is how do I write a scientific calculator class that matches this specification.

```
describe( "ScientificCalculator", function(){
 var calculator;
 beforeEach( function(){
 calculator = new ScientificCalculator();
 } 
);

it( "extends Calculator", function(){
 expect( calculator ).to.be.instanceOf( Calculator );
 expect( calculator ).to.be.instanceOf( ScientificCalculator );
 } 
);

it( "returns the sine of PI / 2", function(){
 expect( calculator.sin( Math.PI / 2 ) ).to.equal( 1 );
 } 
);

it( "returns the cosine of PI", function(){
 expect( calculator.cos( Math.PI ) ).to.equal( -1 );
 } 
);

it( "returns the tangent of 0", function(){
 expect( calculator.tan( 0 ) ).to.equal( 0 );
 } 
);

it( "returns the logarithm of 1", function(){
 expect( calculator.log( 1 ) ).to.equal( 0 );
 } 
);
} 
);
```

Comment: You'll not get much help if you don't provide at least some code YOU tried to write.

Comment: This code is for Scientific Calculator. I wrote my own Calculator class in Javascript. But, the question is how to complete the above specification.

Comment: Please post your ScientificCalculator class and explain what you mean by 'complete the above specification'.

Comment: The above is the incomplete code for a Scientific calculator. I need to complete the above specification in order to make it run

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a standard [JavaScript inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). 
You can use something similar to below to achieve the desired effect. 
Edited code per OPs new data.

```
//Define a calculator base class
var Calculator = function(op1, op2) { 
  this.add = function(op1, op2) { return op1 + op2; }; 
  this.multiply = function(op1, op2) { return op2 * op1; }; 
  this.subtract = function(op1, op2) { return op1 - op2; }; 
  this.divide = function(op1, op2) { 
    if (op1/op2 === Infinity) {
      return Infinity - Infinity; 
    } else return op1/op2; 
  }; 
};


//define a sub class scientific calculator
function ScientificCalculator() {}
ScientificCalculator.prototype = new Calculator();
ScientificCalculator.prototype.constructor = Calculator;
//Add methods to the base class
ScientificCalculator.prototype.sin = function() {
  //Your imlementation here for Sin, repeat same for cos and others
};
var sc = new ScientificCalculator();
```

Comment: var Calculator = function(op1, op2) {
 
 this.add = function(op1, op2) {
    return op1 + op2;
};
  
  this.multiply = function(op1, op2) {
 return op2 * op1;
  };
  
  this.subtract = function(op1, op2) {
 return op1 - op2;
  };
  
  this.divide = function(op1, op2) {
 if (op1/op2 === Infinity) {
  return Infinity - Infinity;
  }
  else
    return op1/op2; 
  };
};  This is the Calculator base class.

Comment: Do I need to do like this:  ScientificCalculator.prototype.sin = function(x) {
  return Math.sin(x);
}; ScientificCalculator.prototype.cos = function(x) {
  return Math.cos(x);
};

Comment: Yes that seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a Calculator class defined somewhere, you could try something like this:

```
function ScientificCalculator() {
  // whatever you want, private variable declarations perhaps?
}

ScientificCalculator.prototype = Object.create(Calculator.prototype);
ScientificCalculator.prototype.constructor = Calculator;

ScientificCalculator.prototype.sin = function(x) {
  return Math.sin(x);
}

ScientificCalculator.prototype.cos = function(x) {
  return Math.cos(x);
}

ScientificCalculator.prototype.tan = function(x) {
  return Math.tan(x);
}

ScientificCalculator.prototype.log = function(x) {
  return Math.log(x);
}
```